# How to setup achievements in uwp...?

Tags: uwp, porting, steam, xbox, achievements

I am porting a game from steam to UWP. I want to How to setup Achievements like steam on UWP. I don't find any useful tutorial regarding this. My Steam code for setting Achievement

```
SteamUserStats.SetAchievement("Achi_Name");
                 SteamUserStats.StoreStats();
```

Comment: Hi, this is about **Xbox Live**, here is the related [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/xbox-live/configure-xbl/dev-center/achievements-in-udc)